# Executing jquery from a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a little project to execute javascript inside a textarea using `eval()`

**HTML**

```
<textarea id='js'><textarea>

<iframe id="inlineframe"></iframe>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
(function(){
$('#js').on('keyup', runjs);
});

function runjs(){ document.getElementById('inlineframe').contentWindow.eval($('#js').val());
}
```

It works great? But what if I didn't just want to execute javascript? What if I wanted it to execute jquery? How to I include that in the function?

Comment: You are using jQuery in your function. Your question makes no sense.

Comment: An IIFE is not a document ready, fwiw

Comment: @GifCo The jquery is just to evaluate javascript in the iframe. What if I wanted to evaluate jquery itself in the iframe?

Comment: As long as jQuery is in scope eval() will just work as normal. You are already using jQuery inside of eval() in your example. eval($('#js').val())

Comment: if your running JS with no issue, once you have jQuery installed it should run with no issue

Comment: @Taplar I thought they said document ready is depreciated?

Comment: Who is "they"?  No, document readies are not deprecated

Comment: My BAD! You're right. `.on( "ready", handler )` was depreciated not `.ready()`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few bugs in your HTML and JS.

- no closing textarea tag, just another textarea element (forgot the /)
- you have an anonymous function encapsulated but don't call it (forgot the () at the end, so it isn't an IIFE)

besides that, there is a simple way to add jQuery to the iFrame: By adding a src attribute to the iFrame and point it to another html-file which has jQuery included just like your current html-file.

If you don't want to create another file, you can add the jQuery file via JS like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="js"></textarea>
<iframe id="inlineframe"></iframe>
<script>
  function runjs() {
    document
      .getElementById("inlineframe")
      .contentWindow.eval($("#js").val());
  }
  (function() {
    $("#js").on("keyup", runjs);
  })();

  const iFrameHead = document.getElementById("inlineframe").contentDocument
    .head;
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src =
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js";
  iFrameHead.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Something to Note: If the iframe's src is from another domain, you won't be able to access its content due to something called **Same Origin Policy.**